# DAX: SUM a data from column C, filtering by column B where relationship is on column A

Tags: excel, powerpivot, dax

[image]

I need help,

I have to data sources in Excel where table A has a UID and table B has that same UID related many to single (many on table B, the single value on table A).

I want to add all the numerical data in column C on file B but only when column B value is "yes" and show that on table A based on the UID relationship between tables.

Comment: Please move the image link on the top down to where you now have the code section with the url text, and replace "enter image description here" with a proper link text stating that this is an image of your tables.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do this with a `SUMX` in a calculated column:

```
YesSumC = SUMX(TableB,
               IF(TableB[Column B] = "yes" &&
                  TableB[UID] = TableA[UID],
                  TableB[Column C], 0))
```

Instead of explicitly matching on `UID` you could also use `RELATEDTABLE` like this:

```
YesSumC = SUMX(RELATEDTABLE(TableB),
               IF(TableB[Column B] = "yes",
                  TableB[Column C], 0))
```